# Running Selenium test presents with a different version of Chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I only have a single installation of chrome in my desktop, but when a simple selenium test is run with chromedriver, the chrome browser version shows up different. The chrome driver version I use is chromedriver@75.1.0. It is clear from chromedriver [documentation](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) chromedriver version closely mimic the version of chrome browser installed, in terms of compatibility.

When I run chrome browser normally here is the version I see:
75.0.3770.142

When I run chrome via selenium here is the version I see:
76.0.3809.87 
[image]

I have tried installing different versions of chromedriver, I had to install

```
npm install chromedriver@^75.0.3770
```

to ensure there are no errors while running.  installing other versions report compatibility issues as expected.

Here is the simple snippet of code which opens chrome browser through selenium.

```
var path = require('chromedriver').path;
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var browser = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
browser.get('https://google.com')
```

When I use “Show in finder” option to look up the directory it is installed it points to the very same location, which makes me wonder there is a single version installed (opened the contents of the package to ensure it is 75.x). 
[image]

I have no clue why chrome version is different when run via selenium.

Comment: Closer inspection of my own question made me relaunch the browser, which shows the same version across both modes!  Keeping this question open, with the hope this may help someone.

Comment: The `chromedriver` doesn't control the browser version, it just use the browser you have. If you want different chrome version you need to install it manually.

Comment: @Guy Yes, thats what i thought. It's just that when Chrome is not relaunched after an update it still shows old version, whereas the one launched by selenium in a new window already shows updated version. One would imagine chrome accurately reflects the version number even in existing window, apparently not!